# Abelian Cartan subalgebras

Tags: lie-algebras

If a Lie algebra is semisimple or reductive, its Cartan subalgebras are Abelian, and their elements semisimple.

> Are there non-reductive algebras with Abelian Cartan subalgebras all of whose elements are semisimple?

**N.B.:** I asked this also on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88802/lie-algebras-with-abelian-cartan-subalgebras).

Comment: Does the same not hold for any reductive Lie algebra, as we can then get a Cartan as the direct sum of a cartan of the derived algebra and the center?

Comment: @Tobias, ah indeed! I actually meant reductive. Fixed!